# Example for a linear algebraic $\mathbb{C}$-group not defined over $\mathbb{Q}$?

Tags: algebraic-groups

Let $G$ be a linear algebraic group, embedded as a Zariski-closed subgroup of $GL(n,\mathbb{C})$ with respect to the identification of $GL(n,\mathbb{C})$ as a subset of $\mathbb{C}^{n^2+1}$ via $M \mapsto (M,\det(M)^{-1})$.

Then $G$ is said to be **defined over $\mathbb{Q}$** if it is the vanishing set of polynomials $f_1,\ldots,f_m \in \mathbb{Q}[X_{11},\ldots,X_{nn},T]$.
All linear algebraic groups I know of are defined over $\mathbb{Q}$, for example $GL(n), SL(n), SO(n)$, invertible diagonal matrices $T_n$, $\mathbb{C}^\times, (\mathbb{C}^n,+)$ etc.

What is an instructive example of a group not defined over $\mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: I'm not sure about affine algebraic groups but elliptic curves with defining equation $y^2=x(x-1)(x-\lambda)$, $\lambda \notin \mathbb{R}$ are examples of abelian varieties without $\mathbb{Q}$-structures

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about the group of matrices of the form $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & x & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & \pi x \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$ for some $x \in \mathbf{C}$? It's obviously *isomorphic* to a group defined over $\mathbf{Q}$ -- the additive group -- but it's embedded into $\mathrm{GL}(4)$ in a weird, non-rational way.

Comment: Do you have an example where the group homomorphism sending it to the group over $\mathbf{Q}$ can't be holomorphic  ? (as for $\mathbf{C}/(\mathbf{Z}+\pi \mathbf{Z})$)

Comment: I don't understand your question: the quotient $C / (Z + \pi Z)$ isn't an algebraic group.